# How can I have one thread do some work and the have another thread join and finish the work?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am currently trying to learn the use of threads, I found an exercise on threads that I am trying to code.

This is the exercise:

> 1. create an application which simulates the running race of 400 meters.
> 2. create five thread groups and give names (Country names).
> 3. The number of runners should be then(two in each group) and give names to each runner thread.
> 4. Each thread should run exactly half the distance - 200 m and the next  thread in the same group should join the race to complete it.
> 5. print the winner group name() and all the threads should complete the race.
> 6. Print the time taken by each Group to complete the race and highlight  the winners time.

So, my question is about the 4th point where each thread should run half the distance, how can I have my initial thread finish and the have the next one replace it and finish the race?

This is my code so far:

```
public class RelayRacerDemo {

public static Thread runner[];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RelayRacer rRacer = new RelayRacer();

    ThreadGroup country[] = new ThreadGroup[5];
    country[0] = new ThreadGroup("USA");
    country[1] = new ThreadGroup("Mexico");
    country[2] = new ThreadGroup("Italia");
    country[3] = new ThreadGroup("France");
    country[4] = new ThreadGroup("Brazil");

    runner = new Thread[10];
    runner[0] = new Thread(country[0] , rRacer, "USA racer 1");
    runner[1] = new Thread(country[0] , rRacer, "USA racer 2");
    runner[2] = new Thread(country[1] , rRacer, "Mexico racer 1");
    runner[3] = new Thread(country[1] , rRacer, "Mexico racer 2");
    runner[4] = new Thread(country[2] , rRacer, "Italia racer 1");
    runner[5] = new Thread(country[2] , rRacer, "Italia racer 2");
    runner[6] = new Thread(country[3] , rRacer, "France racer 1");
    runner[7] = new Thread(country[3] , rRacer, "France racer 2");
    runner[8] = new Thread(country[4] , rRacer, "Brazil racer 1");
    runner[9] = new Thread(country[4] , rRacer, "Brazil racer 2");

    runner[0].start();
    runner[2].start();
    runner[4].start();
    runner[6].start();
    runner[8].start();
}

}
```

and my runnable code:

```
public class RelayRacer implements Runnable{

public static Boolean winnerYet = false;

public void relayRace(){
    for(int distance=1; distance<=40; distance++){
        System.out.println("current runner " + Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                            + " has run " + distance + " meters");
        if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("USA racer 1") && distance == 20){
            threadJoin(distance, 1);
        }else if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Mexico racer 1") && distance == 20){
            threadJoin(distance, 3);
        }else if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Italia racer 1") && distance == 20){
            threadJoin(distance, 5);
        }else if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("France racer 1") && distance == 20){
            threadJoin(distance, 7);                
        }else if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Brazil racer 1") && distance == 20){
            threadJoin(distance, 9);        
        }

        if(isGroupRacerWinner(distance)){
            System.out.println("Winning Country is " + Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().getName());
        }
    }
}


public void threadJoin(int distance, int nextRunner){

        RelayRacerDemo.runner[nextRunner].start();

        try 
        {RelayRacerDemo.runner[nextRunner].join();
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

}

public Boolean isGroupRacerWinner(int distance){

    if(distance == 40 && winnerYet == false){
        winnerYet = true;
        return true;
    }else
        return false;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    this.relayRace();
}
}
```

I changed it to 40 meters so that I could more easily debug my code,

```
runner = thread;
```

This is what's happening: the first runner from each country runs the first 20 meters, and then the second runner joins the race, and runs the whole race (all 40 meters, when it should run only half the race from 20-40 meters.) After the second runner finishes the race, the first runner continues the race and runs the remaining 20 meters from 20-40, (when it should had stop at half the race.)

Comment: If you need to fetch the result of a computation by a `Thread`, you do not *need* to use `Thread.join()`. You can also [use a `future`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53733735/must-you-join-on-a-thread-to-ensure-its-computation-is-complete).

Answer (score 1):

What your code is doing right now:

- One runner runs until 20.
- He then starts the next thread and the `join()` let's him wait until
  the newly started thread finishes.
- The second thread now executes the for loop, but as it is a new
  instance it also starts at 1 and goes until 40.
- Then it is finished and the first thread continues execution (which
  was in the 20th iteration of the for loop).

So in the end you get your 20-40-20 runs.

You need to make sure the second runner doesn't start at one and that the first runner finishes after calling the second runner.

And your check if a team won with `isGroupRacerWinner(distance)` you don't need to do every iteration. It is sufficient if you check it once after the `for` loop. Because the team only have a chance to win if they finish the `for` loop.

Comment: yes you're right, I research before asking and found out that I was getting 20-40-20 runs (as explained at the end of my question.) however, going back to my question, how can I have my initial thread finish and then have the next one replace it and finish the race? by having the second runner start at 20 meter is a good point, but that is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You could just let them both run until 20 instead of 40. Then you're first thread would wait for your second one and both finish at the same time. Or you just add a `break;` into the loop so that the first thread finishes after it has called the second one. But then you need to figure out how to start the second one at 20.