# Why event loop uses more than one thread?

Tags: java, netty

I always thought that asynchronous execution is about efficient resource utilization and thread safety, but today I ran into Netty's strange behavior.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        try {
            bootstrap.group(group)
                     .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                     .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) {
                            channel.pipeline()
                                   .addLast(new ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void read(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
                                            String id = String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId());
                                            ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(id.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
                                               .addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
                                            }
                                        });
                        }
                    })
                    .bind("localhost", 1234)
                    .sync()
                    .channel()
                    .closeFuture()
                    .syncUninterruptibly();
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully()
                 .syncUninterruptibly();
        }
    }
}
```

When I connected for the first time, I got 16. Then 17, 18, 19, etc. Every connection was executed on a new thread! Why? What's the point of Netty, if it's multi-threaded?

Comment: the only point is greater throughput. More clients served at the same time.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov why? What is the difference from the usual multi-threaded server?

Comment: usual multi-threaded server spends a thread per connection. This sets a natural limit about 10000 simultaneous connections. Netty is asynchronous and can keep much more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NioEventLoopGroup` uses worker threads to utilize multiple CPU cores. As per [the no-argument constructor javadoc](https://netty.io/4.1/api/index.html?io/netty/channel/nio/NioEventLoopGroup.html):

> NioEventLoopGroup()
>
> Create a new instance using the default number of threads, the default ThreadFactory and the SelectorProvider which is returned by SelectorProvider.provider().

The deafult thread count as per [`MultithreadEventLoopGroup`](https://github.com/wusi05/netty-source-learning/blob/8e25d3523bbc83e998abcbd6a2ee279c9ca7fff2/netty-netty-4.1.15Final/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java#L40) will be twice the number of available processors:

```
DEFAULT_EVENT_LOOP_THREADS = Math.max(1, SystemPropertyUtil.getInt(
            "io.netty.eventLoopThreads", NettyRuntime.availableProcessors() * 2));
```

Generally this should be enough to saturate the CPU without creating a huge number of threads. Spawn too few threads and you won't get full CPU utilization. Spawn too many and you will waste substantial time context switching between them.

Comment: So I must use synchronization if I need to share the state between connections?

Comment: @Hivemaster if the state is mutable and you don't use CAS (e.g. `AtomicInteger`) while multiple threads are mutating state, yes. You could restrict the number of threads to 1 (`new NioEventLoopGroup(1)`) but on most modern CPUs that's a huge waste.

Comment: @Hivemaster it implements `Future` so it should be but please check class javadoc, e.g. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53734628/1602555). Regarding your previous question sometimes you can get away with just `volatile` but this depends on what is your state.

Comment: That's not a default constructor.